# File Reading Multiple Lines to One String

Tags: java, string, file

I have a JTextArea (aka *"notes"*)where a user can type text and space it in any format they wish. The String is then stored in a file **with other Strings** to be read in late. The "notes" String should be read in later and placed back into the JTextArea with the same formatting as it was originally saved.

If you had 2 text areas, doing this would transfer the correct formatting:

```
JTextArea text1 = new JTextArea();
JTextArea text2 = new JTextArea();

text2.setText(text1.getText);
```

However, writing to a file is different due to the fact that `in.next();` reads *one* String, not an entire text area's worth.

How would you be able to maintain the correct formatting after reading the/multiple Strings in from the text file?

**EDIT:** the file would look something like this:

```
String1
String2
some_long_string
12345
foobar
This string was taken from the JTextArea mentioned above. Imagine that this is all one String and has a lot of whitespace in it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text in a JTextArea can contain newlines, so you must write something in the file that accounts for this.

One way is to write delimiter strings that are very unlikely to appear in the JTextArea's text:

```
String1
String2
some_long_string
12345
foobar
*** BEGIN JTEXTAREA TEXT ***
This string was taken from the JTextArea.
It contains multiple lines.
*** END JTEXTAREA TEXT ***
```

Another way is to escape the newlines.  You could use URLEncoder and URLDecoder, as long as you don't mind that the text will not be very human-readable in the file:

```
String1
String2
some_long_string
12345
foobar
This+string+was+taken+from+the+JTextArea.%0AIt+contains+multiple+lines.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two mechanisms...

1. Use the inbuilt [`read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) method of the `JTextArea` to read the file itself
2. Use the `append` method `JTextArea` to [`append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) new `String`s to the text area.  Just remember, you'll need to supply the new line characters ;)